# Case-Insensitive Check Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, novaclient

Created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLES

(vehicleVIN VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,

vehicleType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (vehicleType IN ('compact', 'midsize', 'fullsize', 'suv', 'truck')),

vehicleWhereFrom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (vehicleWhereFrom IN ('maryland','virginia','washington, d.c.'));
```

When running the insert commands, entries that have capital letters (ex: Compact, COMPACT, Maryland, VIRGINIA, etc.) violate the check constraint (error ORA-02290). How do I make the check constraint case-insensitive? Desired results would be that data inserted is accepted, regardless of case used, as long as the word is spelled correctly. Using Oracle database via NOVA. Thanks!

Comment: Define those columns to have a case insensitive collation.

Comment: So, something like:

vehicleType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY_CI CHECK (vehicleType IN ('compact', 'midsize', 'fullsize', 'suv', 'truck'));

??

Comment: Yes, or other case insensitive collation! (Or other case insensitive collation, depending on your needs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lower` to check the lower case version of the column.

```
CHECK vehicleType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleType) IN ('compact', 'midsize', 'fullsize', 'suv', 'truck')),
CHECK vehicleWhereFrom VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleWhereFrom) IN ('maryland','virginia','washington, d.c.'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this evening when I have access to the server. For some reason, I thought this would only check for anything that is lower cased, but seems to make sense now.

It's been a few years since I've messed with SQL. Thanks for the refresher!

Comment: This did the trick, as expected. Thanks again for helping me recollect my memory! Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(vehicleType,'compact|midsize|fullsize|suv|truck','i'))
```